# Unity script execution order and Start()

Tags: unity-game-engine, order-of-execution

Unity's documentation has this line:

> By default, the Awake, OnEnable and Update functions of different scripts are called in the order the scripts are loaded (which is arbitrary).

So I have two questions here:

1. What does "Arbitrary" mean in this context? Is it random?
2. Does this also include Start() alongside Awake(), or does Start() have its own special behaviour that doesn't follow the script execution order, even if that order has been altered in the project settings?

I've wondered for a while how Unity "decides" how it behaves when it runs, especially since it seems like something will work some of the time but the rest of the time it causes a crash or something with little to no explanation, but the documentation doesn't really mention it much and I can't seem to find much info elsewhere.

Comment: could you not find this out by setting some debug output in these methods and running your game script, so that `Awake` prints something, and `Start` prints something else and you can read the logs as to then clarify which occurs first

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/217941/onenable-awake-start-order.html

Comment: I'm not sure if a bug from 4 and a half years ago is relevant to this question

Comment: See also question and answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252189/gameobject-update-order-in-unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement is somehow confusing.

Awake, OnEnable and Update will **always** be called in order.

> 1.What does "Arbitrary" mean in this context? Is it random?

*Yes*, its random. Although, it is **not** talking about the Awake, OnEnable and Update functions. It is talking about scripts. The scripts are randomly chosen to execute.

> 2.Does this also include Start() alongside Awake(), or does Start() have its own special behaviour that doesn't follow the script
>   execution order, even if that order has been altered in the project
>   settings?

Answer #1 should also answer question #2.
This does not affect the callback functions such as Start() Awake(), or OnEnable().

> I've wondered for a while how Unity "decides" how it behaves when it
>   runs, especially since it seems like something will work some of the
>   time but the rest of the time it causes a crash or something with
>   little to no explanation

Yes, this is true. This has happened to me in the past too. This is more prone to happen when you have large project with many scripts. The scripts are called randomly. Sometimes, you can get null exception error because `GetComponent` failed to work. This is why the *[Script Execution Order Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html)* is made so that you can always set the order in which your scripts execute.

What I do to fix problems like this is to perform `GetComponent` in a coroutine function. After that, I check if it is null. If it is null, wait for one frame then try `GetComponent` again.

*Again, this applies to the order in which your scripts are executed not order in which callback functions are invoked/called.*

Comment: To clarify: The execution order of e.g. all your `Start`-functions in your different scripts is random by default. Sometimes `Start` from `Script A` is executed first, sometimes `Start` from `Script B`, but all `Awake`-functions will be executed before the very first `Start`-function.

Comment: I know about the order of event functions, ie Awake -> Start -> OnEnable -> Update, with every Awake function across all scripts being called before any Start function is. What I wanted to know about was how Unity decides what the order of "Awake" functions is, for example. And you've answered that, it's random, which frankly I think is pretty dumb, but that's Unity I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its random. That randomness event starts when a random script is chosen. The chosen random script will then call its Awake function. To correct you, the order is Awake -> OnEnable-> Start-> Update. @GunnarB I think that's correct and that depends on the script that is chosen to run.

Comment: It could be added that Awake and Start are clearly different, Awake is like a ctor since MB does not expose a ctor. Start is called the first time the script is run. So if you use AddComponent, you get Awake called, if you disable the following line, you get no Start until it gets enabled the first time (along OnEnable). Start will not be run again while OnEnable will.

Comment: @Disturbed could you extend on the thought that the random order is pretty dumb? Hoping the engine is reading your mind is the silly part.

Comment: @Everts I don't think you understand the question and this answer. OP knows the order but is asking the order the callback functions are called with other script callback functions. For example, a Start func from Script A and a Start func from Script B.

Comment: I thought that extended question 2 , as for question 1, the answer is stated in the doc => Arbitrary. Concerning the Script Execution Order, I am not a big fan of it, it does not really suit framework development.

Comment: All I wanted to know is if "arbitrary" in this context actually meant "random" or if it meant Unity's definition of "arbitrary", which is "whatever the default settings happen to be", the difference being whether or not the order is the same every time you run the application. The other thing I wanted to know was if Start() counted as an event function for the purposes of execution order, same as Awake() and Update(), or if it is exempt from such ordering and is arbitrary regardless of settings, as the documentation isn't exactly explicit.

Comment: And it's dumb because it isn't consistent. I can live with it if something crashes 100% of the time because of something I have or haven't done. But when something crashes 1% of the time because script order is chosen AT RANDOM, it's very difficult to replicate, even with Debugging. I just feel like there should be some consistent default that means the order is the same every time your app is run, even if that order is bad.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I've had this problem and discovered `Script Execution Order Settings` by luck. At-least, you have a way to fix it so use `Script Execution Order Settings` if you notice that your code throws the null exception sometimes. Another way to solve that is to use coroutine for your GetComponent request like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I think GetComponent in coroutine may be the way forward. Thing is, if I have a package that uses scripts to interface with a plugin, I can't use project settings to specify script order, since that will vary from project to project and by default it will always be "arbitrary". Thanks.

Comment: Yup. That too. I use less package/plugin and I will tell you that the less plugin you use, the less problem you will have with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html you can set the order the scripts load manually. If you don't set an order my guess is that Unity uses some predefined order (random, alphabetical or something)

**Question 2**

Awake() allways runs before Start() and is called when the script is loaded https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html.

To load the scripts in a specific order you need to use the script execution order. To make sure you run the Start() function of each object in a specific order you need to make a "Manager" object that instantiates the objects in the order you wish.

Comment: Apparently if you don't set anything the order is random. I know that Awake() runs before Start(), I simply meant is Start() affected by the script execution order, because the documentation implies that it isn't.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Start() is run as soon as an object enables a script, right before the Update() is run. So the order in which the different Start() are run is determined by the order you enable the scripts

Comment: Well exactly, it's confusing. Documentation says "Awake, OnEnable and Update Functions" are called in the script execution order, but doesn't mention Start(), so when a scene first starts up, after all the Awake functions are called, what happens with the Start() functions. Are they called in the same order, or is their order arbitrary anyway, which would make it a different order to the awake functions?

Comment: Well, ok. Objects already in the scene I am unsure about. Can you test this by logging something in the different Start() functions and see if it seems random or not?
This is why I wrote that to guarantee the order you need to use some sort of "Manager" object that instantiates your objects when pressing play.