# The gold is set to a value instead of adding that value to the gold

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a currency system and I came across a problem that I can't fix. Basically instead of adding the value to the gold, the gold is set to the value. Can anyone help fix that

Main Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class levelBeaten : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject finishCollider;
    public GameObject finishPopup;
    public currencyHandler currency;

    private int sceneIndex;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        finishPopup.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;

        // Check if gold has already been claimed in this scene
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("GoldClaimedInScene" + sceneIndex))
        {
            Debug.Log("Gold has already been claimed in scene " + sceneIndex);
            return; // Gold has already been claimed
        }

        // Gold has not been claimed, add it and save the claim
        int goldToAdd = sceneIndex == 1 ? 300 : sceneIndex == 2 ? 500 : 0;
        currency.AddGold(goldToAdd);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GoldClaimedInScene" + sceneIndex, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            levelfinishedpopup();
        }
    }

    public void levelfinishedpopup()
    {
        finishPopup.SetActive(true);

        Animator animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        animator.SetTrigger("popupAnimation");

        // Wait for the animation to finish playing
        float animationLength = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndStopTime(animationLength));
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitAndStopTime(float waitTime)
    {
        // Wait for the specified time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        // Set the time scale to 0
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

}
```

Currency Handler:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class currencyHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gold = 0;
    public GameObject currencyUI;

    private TextMeshProUGUI currencyText;

    private const string GOLD_KEY = "gold";

    void Start()
    {
        currencyText = currencyUI.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        LoadGold();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currencyText.text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
        if (gold < 0)
        {
            gold = 0;
        }
    }

    public void AddGold(int amount)
    {
        gold += amount;
        SaveGold();
    }

    private void SaveGold()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(GOLD_KEY, gold);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void LoadGold()
    {
        gold = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(GOLD_KEY, 0);
    }
}
```

I tried making it so when the players collides with the finish line if the scene index is 1 it gives you 400 gold and if the scene index is 2 it gives you 500 gold and you can only get the gold once from each scene. But instead of adding the value to the gold it set the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity script execution order and Start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358698/unity-script-execution-order-and-start)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
void Start()
{
  currencyText = currencyUI.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
  LoadGold();
}
```

to this instead:

```
void Awake()
{
  currencyText = currencyUI.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
  LoadGold();
}
```

You need to load the gold before you do everything else, and to do this you need to use the Awake method as it gets called before the Start method.