# Is update order execution in unity constant?

Tags: unity-game-engine, execution

Assuming two things:

1.- That there is no defined order for the `Update()` function execution and that If a specific order is needed, you can define it yourself with the script execution order as specified [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/46107/in-what-order-are-all-the-update-functions-called.html), and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

2.- That the gameobjects are not updated according to their hierarchy as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252189/gameobject-update-order-in-unity)

Something I could not clear out from the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) is if you do not set any order for the script execution, once this is set 'randomly' by unity, if this order remains unaltered through the execution of the game or if the update execution order may change in time.

Comment: Documentation says straight not to depend on it, while the order shouldn't normally change in runtime, tere is no guarantee that it won't. If you really need your fixed order, use your own update function instead of the built in one (and run it from a designated instance of a manager)

Comment: The script execution order can only define an order between different scripts/components .. it doesn't define the order between multiple instances of the same type if that is what you are asking -> see e.g. [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1507401/define-execution-order-same-script-on-multiple-gam.html)

Comment: So you are saying that even if the script order execution is set in the project, the order between multiple instances of the same type will still be random, right? It makes sense as you define the script order, not the instance order....

Comment: Thanks for your point. My question may now have this case included also :) (I did not think of it when I asked). When I worte it, it was reagrding the script order (not the instances) consistency if the order execution is not defined

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify anything, the order won't be consistent. If you want a specific script to execute before others you HAVE to use the script execution order or use an array has suggested in you linked post.