# In Unity, does different "yield return X" Coroutine always run in order?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

【code】

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(A1());
    StartCoroutine(A2());
    StartCoroutine(A3());
}

IEnumerator A1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("A1");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
IEnumerator A2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("A2");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
IEnumerator A3()
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("A3");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

【output】

A1
A2
A3
A1
A2
A3
A1
A2
A3
A1
A2
A3
...

【My Quesion】

A1(),A2(),A3() always run in order.

Is it for sure or not?
Is it the same for "yield return null", "yield return WaitForSeconds" and other "yield return X"?

Why I have this question?
In Unity's [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), different kinds of "yield return X" happens at different time.
Then I want to know, if several same kind of "yield return X"(in the same MonoBehaviour) always happens in order.

## Update1

### 1.1

In the comment, @joreldraw says

> Change your A1 to 20 seconds, A2 to 10, and try again :)

Here is code and output.

【code】

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(A1());
    StartCoroutine(A2());
}

IEnumerator A1()
{
    while (true)
    {

        print($"A1,frame:{Time.frameCount},time:{Time.time}");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    }   
}
IEnumerator A2()
{
    while (true)
    {

        print($"A2,frame:{Time.frameCount},time:{Time.time}");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    }
}
```

【output】

A1,frame:3187,time:10.00139
A2,frame:6495,time:20.0001
A1,frame:6496,time:20.00392
A1,frame:9686,time:30.00965
A2,frame:13093,time:40.0004
A1,frame:13095,time:40.01266
A1,frame:16445,time:50.01303
A2,frame:19695,time:60.00157
A1,frame:19699,time:60.01489

### 1.2

What I want to know is, if they keep in order when they are at same frame.
So I change time to 0.01s and 0.02s .

【output】

A1,frame:3,time:0.3533334
A2,frame:3,time:0.3533334
...
A2,frame:10,time:0.4100522
A1,frame:11,time:0.4132612
A1,frame:15,time:0.4247341
...
A1,frame:38,time:0.4942196
A2,frame:38,time:0.4942196
...
A2,frame:52,time:0.5754243
A1,frame:52,time:0.5754243
A1,frame:54,time:0.5914614
...

### 1.3

It is hard to figure out if the coroutines keep in order. So I modified code, only do printing when the coroutines run at the same frame.

```
HashSet<int> a1Set = new HashSet<int>();
HashSet<int> a2Set = new HashSet<int>();
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(A1());
    StartCoroutine(A2());
}

IEnumerator A1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        a1Set.Add(Time.frameCount);
        if (a2Set.Contains(Time.frameCount))
        {
            print($"First 2, Then 1, frame:{Time.frameCount}");
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    }   
}
IEnumerator A2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        a2Set.Add(Time.frameCount);
        if (a1Set.Contains(Time.frameCount))
        {
            print($"First 1, Then 2, frame:{Time.frameCount}");
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
    }
}
```

【output】

First 1, Then 2, frame:3
First 1, Then 2, frame:4
First 2, Then 1, frame:9
First 2, Then 1, frame:16
First 2, Then 1, frame:22
First 2, Then 1, frame:28
First 1, Then 2, frame:76
First 1, Then 2, frame:135
First 1, Then 2, frame:179
First 2, Then 1, frame:186
First 1, Then 2, frame:222

Comment: Change your A1 to 20 seconds, A2 to 10, and try again :)

Comment: @joreldraw why? I don't think that is the question here ^^

Comment: What is your actual usecase? Why not  simply use one single routine that does A0-4 in order every 3 seconds?

Comment: @derHugo No usecase here. Just this question comes into my mind ^^ (so it may be a pointless question).   I know about Unity's "Order of execution for event", different kinds of "yield return X" happens at different time. Then I want to know, if several same kind of "yield return X"(in the same MonoBehaviour) happens in order.

Comment: @joreldraw I did some test according to your comment. They have been already added to the post.

Comment: Well `0.01s and 0.02s` are unlikely to happen in the same frame .. why should they? Usually assuming 60 f/s you have frames with a length of `0.017` seconds so your values will never exactly match  ... also still ... what usecase is this? The question makes little sense to me ... Your coroutines are of course executed in the same order .. but if one finishes to wait twice as fast and often .. how can you even expect that the order stays the same?

Comment: @derHugo You are smarter about the time.
If the frame rate is locked to 60, it is much better to use 0.017 than 0.01.
The test output is almost the same. So please forgive me about not updating the post.

Comment: Then, for my question:

Comment: 【1】
I'm not sure about "Your coroutines are of course executed in the same order".

Comment: 【2】
Let's see a similar problem: Update() call order of different GameObjects.
For example, I Instantiate 10 GameObjects one by one, each of them have a ComponentA.
Will the Update() calls of these 10 ComponentA be in order?

Comment: 【3】
I did a test, it shows that Update() calls are in order.

Comment: 【4】
But if I search on Internet, it would say that you can't rely on the order. The order is not for sure. 
I found 2 posts : 
https://answers.unity.com/questions/46107/in-what-order-are-all-the-update-functions-called.html ，
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252189/gameobject-update-order-in-unity

Comment: 【5】
For Update() call of different GameObject, the order is not for sure.
Then, the order of coroutines may also be not for sure.

Comment: I think I'm too nitpicking about this. (But I'm this kind of guy... There are chances I come to this kind of question...) .
There is no usecase. This is not an important question. 
If I want the coroutines to be in some order, I can implement it yourself. Thus I don't need to rely on the order.
But I still wish someone to answer my question.

Comment: Well, the only answer you will find here is probably: Don't rely on the order ^^ without a specific usecase this forum might not be the best place to ask this question ;)

Comment: Yeah. Anyway, thank you. I find you very patient. Very nice time talking with you.

Comment: @AdmiralOrange add a debug line and print result after the waitfor second for the result of execution, you are only debuging the start without the wait time.:
print($"A2 Start ,frame:{Time.frameCount},time:{Time.time}");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
print($"A2 END,frame:{Time.frameCount},time:{Time.time}");

Answer (score 0):

In your described case yes! The order is always the same because you start them one after another and they all wait 3 seconds so the first ones always has the head start. It's the same for yield return null because then it's executed in the next frame. It gets tricky when you start the couroutines from different Update()/Start() methods because the exectuion order of those is not guaranteed. If you need them to execute in a specific order try different wait intervals or use other unity functions described here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html?_ga=2.194867501.1256475209.1612055407-571780476.1550264998#Coroutines

Comment: Thank you.
I know about "Order of execution for event". It says different kind of yield return happens at different time. But it does not say if same yield return happens in order or not.  So I ask this question.

Comment: I think this question( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932306/how-does-startcoroutine-yield-return-pattern-really-work-in-unity ) may help me. it is a bit long, I haven't read.

Comment: Same yield return happens in order of there start. If you for example have 2 cooroutines with yield return WaitForSeconds(2) both continue after 2 seconds but the one you started first executes earlier because it began to earlier to wait because it was executed at first

Comment: More test added. In Update1 - 1.3, "yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);" vs "yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);" will not happen in order. Check it if you are interested.

Comment: Yeah obviously because the wait times are different

Answer (score 0):

The start of the coroutine follow the order of your code:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(A1()); //Firt
    StartCoroutine(A2()); //Second
}
```

The result of the coroutine depend of the time of execution you add for wait:

```
IEnumerator A1()
{
    Debug.Log("Started Coroutine A1 at : " + Time.time);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

     //Here your code for the result after waitforsecond
     Debug.Log("Finished Coroutine A1 at : " + Time.time);   
}
IEnumerator A2()
{
     Debug.Log("Started Coroutine at A2 : " + Time.time);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);

     //Here your code for the result after waitforsecond
     Debug.Log("Finished Coroutine A2 at : " + Time.time);
}
```